# Swift passing parameters from iPhone to web API

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, iphone, swift

I have an API built to my rails application and the following curl works:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" \
-H "X-AccessToken: a602a4a8-1a77-4437-90bc-bb2023bbd2b5" \
http://localhost:3000/api/guesstimate \
-d '{"guesstimation": {"breed_id":"593","gender":"Male","age_years":"5"}}'
```

Now I want to do the equivalent within my iphone app.  I have the following so far:

```
    let api_token = "a602a4a8-1a77-4437-90bc-bb2023bbd2b5"
    let urlPath = "http://localhost:3000/api/guesstimate"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)

    //set up the request
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.addValue("application/json; charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue(api_token, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-AccessToken")
```

When I fire this, I can see it hit the API (in the rails console), so I'm communicating, but it's failing of course because the expected parameters are not present.

I'm not sure how to encode the parameters (breed_id, etc) into the request.  I've tried a few approaches like building a query string by hand, but it seems very brittle.  Seems like I should be able to build a bit of json and then just add it to the request with a one liner, but the usual amount of googling hasn't yielded any insight.

I also need to nest the parameters within "guesstimate" as in the curl because that's what rails expects to see.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the body for your request `request.HTTPBody` with something like `NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params)`

Comment: Thanks Leito! Exactly what I needed.